# How to get the count of the field in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table `orders` whose structure is like this:

```
create table orders (id serial primary key, created_at timestamp, updated_at timestamp, product_id varchar[]);
```

I for the product_id I am inserting data like this:

```
insert into orders values (1,now(),now(),'{"1","2"}');
```

the `product_id` holds the different products that were ordered in a particular order. There is a entry in `products` table for each of the `product_id`.

Now I want to get the counts of the `product_id` for a particular order.

Example: For the above insertion I made, I should get something like:

```
Id    Count
1     2
```

How is it possible is postgresql?

Edit: Sorry for messing with the `create table` query. It's a varchar[] instead of varchar(255)

Comment: Normalize the schema and use a linking table to link products to orders along with the quantity. (Read ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad?r=SearchResults&s=1|192.9954).) Then this is easy. And BTW 9.3 isn't supported any longer, consider upgrading.

Comment: Show us you've tried something and I'll fix it if there you have issues.

Comment: @stickybit I am doing this as a hobby project to learn the backend development. I too found out that this is a bad practice. I'm thinking of having a third table to link the products and orders instead of writing this as a list of production. Stil wanted to know if this is possible in any way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh sorry. it's a `varchar[]`. have updated the question

Comment: You should nevertheless upgrade to a supported and maintained Postgres version as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the value to an array and measure the number of values:

```
select o.*, cardinality(product_id)
from orders o
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I get the error saying `string_to_array function` doesn't exist

Comment: `select o.*, cardinality(product_id)
from orders o;` this works though

Comment: Another solution I found is by using the array_length() function 
`SELECT coalesce(array_length(product_id, 1), 0) as size FROM orders;`

Answer (score 0):

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (id integer, count json);

INSERT INTO tbl1 (id, count) values (1, '["1", "2"]'::json), (2, '["3", "45"]');
```

Query:

```
 SELECT id, sum(json_array_length(count)) as count from tbl1 group by id order by id;
```

Result:

```
 id | count 

----+-------

  1 |     2

  2 |     2
```

I do hope it helps

Comment: for this it would require me to change the table structure and migrate the data. For the existing table structure, I did find a couple of ways to do but not sure if it is correct. Will update in a while

Comment: You didn't give your DDL statements, at least initially, so I had to improvise @SuloveBista